# Swift - Iterating over an array of dictionaries, while retrieving a value from each one

Tags: json, swift

I'm using a web API that returns an array of dictionaries. For instance, it returns an array of 9 dictionaries, and inside each dictionary is a key named "title".

I've tried the following code and it crashes with an error of unwrapping an optional value:

```
for dict in returnedJson {

            if let validTitle = dict["title"] as? String {
                print(validTitle)
                dataList.append(validTitle)
            } else {
                print("Optional title?")
            }
        }
```

The list of titles is printed in the console due to the print(validTitle) line, but the array I'm using to populate the tableview with doesn't seem to want to append it.

I know it's probably something really basic thats eluding me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: do you initialize datalist? Where is the crash and what is the unwrapped optional?

Comment: We need to see more of the code. Specifically, we need to see how you define `dataList`. Also, there is no forced unwrapping happening in your code sample, so where exactly is the unwrapping optional error occurring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have most likely defined `dataList` as an implicitly unwrapped optional. That's why you don't need to use optional chaining when calling append on it but if the `dataList` is nil it would still throw an error since it is trying to unwrap it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem:
1)make sure dataList is a NSMutableArray 
2)create a var of type string right before you append 
example:

```
var recs:NSArray = jsonObj.objectForKey("pets")?.objectForKey("records") as! NSArray
for item in recs{
    var arr:NSArray = item as! NSArray
    var name:String = arr[1] as! String
    println(arr[2] as! String)
    self.recsAddr.addObject(name)
}
```

Comment: The OP's JSON deserializes to a dictionary, not an array. Also the OP appears to be using Swift arrays and dictionaries, not their Cocoa counterparts. Finally, all of the `as!` forced downcasts are just begging for runtime errors, especially working with a JSON object from a remote server, where you cannot guarantee the structure of the data being received.

Comment: Thanks guys. Yeah it was a silly mistake in the initialization of the dataList (I'm still learning). I appreciate the feedback from everyone and will look into the functional programming paradigm appzyourlyfe

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the others, with that error log I suspect you are using an *implicitly unwrapped optional* that happen to be nil. We'll need more code for this.

Generally speaking, this kind of problem fits well the **Functional Programming Paradigm** (so loved by Swift) and can be solved as follow.

```
let returnedJson : [NSDictionary] = [["title":"one"], ["no title here":""], [:], ["title":"four"], ["title":"five"], ["title":"six"]]

let titles = returnedJson
    .map { return $0["title"] } // now we have a list of titles/nil [String?] 
    .filter { return $0 != nil} // now we have a list of titles (without nil)
    .map { return $0! } // now we have this return type [String]

titles // -> ["one", "four", "five", "six"]
```

Hope this helps.